# Can I use deficiency in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can I use deficiency in this sentence?

"Due to the deficiency of geographical points (stop's latitude and longitude) in the database, the visualization of the route between the related stops was not serviceable since a Polyline in Google maps is a drawn as a straight line between two points and to display the real route in the map  many other points must be added into the database between each two stops."

.[image]

Comment: As a programmer, I'm sure you're familiar with the term "obfuscation." To me, this is obfuscation - I would choose a more common word. But maybe that's my personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead word it something something like this--

"Due to the lack of geographical points that represent the route between stops in the database, the related bus stops are connected by straight lines when displayed in a Google map. To display the actual route in the map, the polyline would need to be densified by adding more points between the stops."

Comment: "Densified by adding," that's nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Deficiency** in your example is usable, but probably a better way of saying this would be **lack of**:

> ...the **lack of** geographical points...

There are other concerns with the rest of the text...